# Elastic Search Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch

Is there any console interface available for ElasticSearch similar to Ruby IRB or Rails console? Is there any GUI tool to query ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take a look at this: https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head

It's not a console, but an interface to explore the indexed data, query the index etc.

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamai.net](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/5f01aae07364c95b6c8ddfe39423d6d19932158d/687474703a2f2f6d6f627a2e6769746875622e636f6d2f656c61737469637365617263682d686561642f73637265656e73686f74732f636c75737465724f766572766965772e706e67))</sub>

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answers when they solve your problem ;)

Comment: The tool is awesome. Any way to also see the mappings put into the index?

Answer (score 1):

Even a Rest plugin for Mozilla Firefox will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Bigdesk is another console option for elasticsearch:

https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk

[image]